# What is an efficient BASH one-liner for adding line every 130 characters to a file without lines?

Tags: bash, command-line, tokenize

I am trying to process some largish files which lack line separators.  I would like to process them with line-oriented tools like grep and sed.

I'd like to put something on the front of my pipeline that will insert a newline every 130 characters.  I'm not interested in modifying the input files.

What is an efficient BASH one-liner for adding line every 130 characters to a file without lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want efficient, there is special command (part of coreutils) for this:

```
fold -w130 file | ...
```

Comment: Elegant.  Much cleaner than my solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered the answer in the asking.  Another way to phrase this question to understand this answer is: What is an efficient BASH one-liner for reading a file without lines 130 characters at a time?

The answer is the BASH builtin `read`.  It is a powerful tool that is well-suited to this purpose.

```
cat unlined_data.txt | while read -n130 record ; do echo $record ; done # | rest of pipeline
```

There may be a more elegant solution and I'd be happy to see one.

Comment: You really want `read -r`, and `echo "$record"`. Even so, you will find that space characters will occasionally be deleted (if they happen to show up at the end of the 130 characters read). Use `fold` for more precision.

Comment: The fix for missing whitespace is to set IFS to nothing: `while IFS= read -r -n130 record; do echo "$record"; done`